# The kafka channel in flume monitors a json data, and then uses kafka to consume and finds that each line of escape characters is garbled

Tags: apache-kafka, flume

This is my flume file

```
a1.sources=r1
a1.channels=c1

a1.sources.r1.type = TAILDIR
a1.sources.r1.positionFile = /home/hadoop/taildir_position.json
a1.sources.r1.filegroups = f1
a1.sources.r1.filegroups.f1 = /home/hadoop/data.*

a1.channels.c1.kafka.parseAsFlumeEvent=false
a1.channels.c1.type=org.apache.flume.channel.kafka.KafkaChannel
a1.channels.c1.brokerList=centos01:9092
a1.channels.c1.topic=test

a1.sources.r1.channels=c1
```

I use the following command to consume kafka

```
kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server centos01:9092 --topic test --from-beginning
```

Then the following problem arises, and my escape characters all turn into a question mark
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jcDAH.png)

Comment: I believe the data is being serialized as Avro strings as it enters the Kafka channel. Try setting `kafka.producer.value.serializer` setting to use StringSerializer

Comment: Thank you, at your prompt I replaced the kafka channel with kafka sink and successfully imported the data into hdfs

Comment: What's reading from Kafka to write to HDFS? Also, btw, many Flume developers went to work on StreamSets years ago, which is mostly free, but also more feature complete. Apache Nifi would also be an option. I generally think Flume docs are hard to interpret

Comment: A log file in json format , I think I still have a lot to learn,Come on

Comment: Not sure I understand? A "log file" is not a Kafka consumer or HDFS writer? My question was more related to the fact that your Flume config doesn't shown an HDFS Sink, so if you used a Kafka sink instead of a channel, how does data actually get to HDFS?

Comment: I rewrote a configuration file again, and I see what you mean. There is an HDFS sink in another file, which I use kafka for caching, which is another file of mine. 
`a2.sources = r2
a2.channels = c2
a2.sinks = k2
a2.sources.r2.type = org.apache.flume.source.kafka.KafkaSource
a2.sources.r2.kafka.bootstrap.servers = centos01:9092
a2.sources.r2.kafka.topics=test
a2.channels.c2.type = file
a2.sinks.k2.type = hdfs
a2.sinks.k2.hdfs.path = hdfs://192.168.170.133:9000/flume/%y-%m-%d
a2.sinks.k2.hdfs.fileType=DataStream
a2.sinks.k2.channel = c2
a2.sources.r2.channels=c2`